# how can I access the __zone_symbol__value on the ZoneAwarePromise in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am receiving a ZoneAwarePromise and when I logged it to the console I found that it contains a __zone_symbol__value I was wondering if it's possible to set a variable equal to that __zone_symbol__value?

Comment: please did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 17):

I'm doing it like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {    
    console.log(" Ticket initialized");
    this.getBranchTickets().then(data => console.log(data));
  }

  getBranchTickets() {
   return this.ticketService.getBranchTickets().$promise;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

As you know storage.get returns a promise, not the value. 
You'll need to unwrap the promise in a .then

```
strorage.get('key')
.then( res => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 3):

you are receiving this __zone_symbol__value, because you have mistakenly including your async validator returning promise in the sync validators list, try changing the posiiton of your validator, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

in your view you can access with pipe async

( variable | async)?.field

Answer (score 2):

the caller of the async method needs to be async as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
async onEditConfirm(event): Promise<void> {
    //async/await the method returning your => __zone_symbol__value
    await event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
    //at this point your async operation will have completed
    this.onSave();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually declare my observables with a $ symbol notation to keep track, for example:

```
this.profile$: any;
this.profile: any;

this.profile$ = navParams.get('profile');
```

Utilising the **then()** method to return the promise, I populate a variable free of the $ notation

```
const self = this;

this.profile$.then(val => self.profile = val);
```

I set a constant of **self** retaining the **this** global object otherwise the promise itself is referred to, rather than the parent.

Hope this helps someone simplify the process.

Answer (score 0):

```
async yourFunction(){
    const Ref0 = firebase.firestore().collection("your_collection").doc(doc.id)

    const Ref1 = appointmentsRef.where('val1', '==',condition1).get();
    const Ref2 = appointmentsRef.where("val2", "!=", condition2).get()

    const [snapshot_val1, snapshot_val2] = await Promise.all([Ref1, Ref2]);

    
    const val1_Array = snapshot_val1.docs;
    const val2_Array = snapshot_val2.docs;

    const globale_val_Array = val1_Array .concat(val2_Array );

    return globale_val_Array ;
  }



/*Call you function*/
this.checkCurrentAppointment().then(docSnapshot=> {
      docSnapshot.forEach(doc=> {
          console.log("Your data with multiple code query:", doc.data());
      });
    });
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28443095)

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that you are not returning an asynchronous object (Observable or Promise for example) instead of primitive, Object, Array e etc